# My CoverPanel component can't display PDF on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I'm encountering a problem with Safari. I have a ReactJS component called "CoverPanel" that displays PDF or image on page. It's working on Chrome and Firefox but on Safari, when I load the component with PDF viewer, the PDF viewer displaying just a gray background, no PDF content on it. Refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

This is the code of the CoverPanel:

```
return (
    <CoverPanel
      isMediaFullWidth={false}
      initialized={showContent && initialized}
      isPlayerDisabled={disabledPlayer}
      isPlayerStop={isPlayerStop}
      mediaFilename={mediaFilename}
      min={isPassageMin}
      max={isPassageMax}
      onMinimize={() => dispatch(minimizePassageAction())}
      onMaximize={() => dispatch(maximizePassageAction())}
      onOpenNewTab={
        mediaFileType === 'image' || mediaFileType === 'pdf'
          ? () => {
              dispatch(openNewTabPassageAction(url));
            }
          : null
      }
      onPlayerPlay={() => dispatch(playPlayerAction())}
      onPlayerPlaying={(value) => {
        dispatch(playingPlayerAction(value));
      }}
      onPlayerRateChange={(value) => {
        dispatch(changePlayerSpeedAction(value));
      }}
      onPlayerSeekChange={(value) => {
        dispatch(changePlayerSegmentAction(value));
      }}
      onPlayerStop={(value) => {
        dispatch(stopPlayerAction(value));
      }}
      onPlayerWait={(value) => {
        dispatch(waitPlayerAction(value));
      }}
      playerSegment={segment}
      playerSpeed={speed}
      title="Passage"
      transcript={passage}
      type={mediaFileType}
      url={url}
      isSpeak={true}
    />
  );
```

Then this is the origin of the CoverPanel.

```
import { FC, ReactElement, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Box,
  CircularProgress,
  makeStyles,
  Theme,
  Tooltip,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import {
  Error,
  Fullscreen,
  FullscreenExit,
  Remove,
  Tab,
} from '@material-ui/icons';
import { Skeleton } from '@material-ui/lab';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import PropTypes, { InferProps } from 'prop-types';
import VideoJs from 'video.js';
import { Center } from 'components/center';
import { Image } from 'components/image';
import { IconButton } from 'components/icon-button';
import { LessMenu } from 'components/icons';
import { Panel } from 'components/panel';
import { PanelContent } from 'components/panel-content';
import { PanelHeader } from 'components/panel-header';
import { Player } from 'components/player';
import { getFileExtension } from 'utils/get-file-extension';

/**
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {boolean} initialized
 * @property {boolean} min
 * @property {boolean} max
 * @property {Function} onOpenNewTab
 * @property {Function} onMinimize
 * @property {Function} onMaximize
 * @property {'image' | 'pdf' | 'audio' | 'video'} type
 * @property {string} url
 */
const propTypes = {
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  isMediaFullWidth: PropTypes.bool,
  initialized: PropTypes.bool,
  isPlayerDisabled: PropTypes.bool,
  isPlayerStop: PropTypes.bool,
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  mediaFilename: PropTypes.string,
  min: PropTypes.bool,
  max: PropTypes.bool,
  onOpenNewTab: PropTypes.func,
  onMinimize: PropTypes.func,
  onMaximize: PropTypes.func,
  onPlayerPlay: PropTypes.func,
  onPlayerPlaying: PropTypes.func,
  onPlayerRateChange: PropTypes.func,
  onPlayerSeekChange: PropTypes.func,
  onPlayerStop: PropTypes.func,
  onPlayerWait: PropTypes.func,
  playerSegment: PropTypes.number,
  playerSpeed: PropTypes.number,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  transcript: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(['image', 'pdf', 'audio', 'video']),
  url: PropTypes.string,
  isSpeak: PropTypes.bool,
};

type Props = InferProps<typeof propTypes>;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: '100%',
  },
  content: {
    display: 'block',
  },
  error: {
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    display: 'flex',
    '& .MuiBox-root[role="title"]': {
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      '& .MuiTypography-root': {
        fontWeight: 700,
      },
    },
    '& .MuiBox-root[role="actions"]': {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
  },
  imageContain: {
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    maxHeight: '100%',
    maxWidth: '100%',
  },
  imageFullWidth: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  media: {
    margin: '0 -1px -1px',
  },
  min: {
    '&$root': {
      height: 'auto',
      overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    '&$content': {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  object: {
    display: 'block',
  },
  player: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
    borderTopRightRadius: 0,
    height: '100%',
  },
  skeleton: {
    minHeight: '100px',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  },
  transcript: {
    paddingBottom: '16px',
    fontSize: '1rem',
    lineHeight: 1.5,
    '& .bold': {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    '& .italic': {
      fontStyle: 'italic',
    },
    '& .underline, u': {
      textDecoration: 'underline',
      textDecorationSkipInk: 'none',
    },
  },
}));

/**
 * CoverPanel
 * cover panel component
 *
 * @param {Props}
 *
 * @returns {import('react').ReactElement}
 */
export const CoverPanel: FC<Props> = ({
  error = false,
  isMediaFullWidth = true,
  initialized,
  isPlayerDisabled,
  isPlayerStop,
  loading = false,
  mediaFilename,
  min = false,
  max = false,
  onMinimize,
  onMaximize,
  onOpenNewTab,
  onPlayerPlay,
  onPlayerPlaying,
  onPlayerRateChange,
  onPlayerSeekChange,
  onPlayerStop,
  onPlayerWait,
  playerSegment,
  playerSpeed = 1,
  title,
  transcript,
  type,
  url,
  isSpeak = false,
}): ReactElement => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const playerRef = useRef<VideoJs>(null);

  const disableContextMenuRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  /**
   * This prevents the user from right-clicking the video
   *
   * @param e
   * @returns
   */
  const handelOnRightClick = (e: MouseEvent): boolean => {
    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
  };

  /**
   * Pauses the passage media player when isPlayerStop is TRUE.
   * e.g. when recording has been detected.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlayerStop && (type === 'video' || type === 'audio')) {
      playerRef?.current?.pause();
    }
  }, [isPlayerStop]);

  useEffect(() => {
    playerRef?.current?.currentTime(playerSegment);
    if (disableContextMenuRef.current !== null) {
      disableContextMenuRef.current.addEventListener(
        'contextmenu',
        handelOnRightClick,
      );
    }

    return () => {
      if (disableContextMenuRef.current !== null) {
        disableContextMenuRef.current.removeEventListener(
          'contextmenu',
          handelOnRightClick,
        );
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Panel className={clsx(classes.root, min && classes.min)}>
      <PanelHeader
        className={classes.header}
        color="charcoal"
        disabledTypography
      >
        {initialized ? (
          <>
            <Box role="title">
              <Typography variant="body1">{title}</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box role="actions">
              {typeof onOpenNewTab === 'function' && (
                <Tooltip arrow title="Open in a new tab">
                  <IconButton
                    color="inherit"
                    disabled={url === null}
                    size="small"
                    onClick={onOpenNewTab}
                  >
                    <Tab />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              )}
              {typeof onMinimize === 'function' && (
                <IconButton color="inherit" size="small" onClick={onMinimize}>
                  {/* <Tooltip arrow title={min ? 'Maximize' : 'Minimize'}></Tooltip> */}
                  <Tooltip
                    arrow
                    title={
                      min
                        ? isSpeak
                          ? 'Expand'
                          : 'Maximize'
                        : isSpeak
                        ? 'Collapse'
                        : 'Minimize'
                    }
                  >
                    {min ? <LessMenu /> : <Remove />}
                  </Tooltip>
                </IconButton>
              )}
              {typeof onMaximize === 'function' && (
                <IconButton color="inherit" size="small" onClick={onMaximize}>
                  {/* <Tooltip
                    arrow
                    title={max ? 'Exit full screen' : 'Full screen'}
                  > */}
                  <Tooltip
                    arrow
                    title={
                      max
                        ? isSpeak
                          ? 'Minimize'
                          : 'Exit full screen'
                        : isSpeak
                        ? 'Maximize'
                        : 'Full screen'
                    }
                  >
                    {max ? <FullscreenExit /> : <Fullscreen />}
                  </Tooltip>
                </IconButton>
              )}
            </Box>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Box role="title">
              <Skeleton variant="text" width={70} />
            </Box>
            <Box role="actions">
              {typeof onOpenNewTab === 'function' && (
                <Box
                  mr={
                    typeof onMinimize === 'function' ||
                    typeof onMaximize === 'function'
                      ? 1
                      : 0
                  }
                >
                  <Skeleton height={30} variant="circle" width={30} />
                </Box>
              )}
              {typeof onMinimize === 'function' && (
                <Box mr={typeof onMaximize === 'function' ? 1 : 0}>
                  <Skeleton height={30} variant="circle" width={30} />
                </Box>
              )}
              {typeof onMaximize === 'function' && (
                <Box>
                  <Skeleton height={30} variant="circle" width={30} />
                </Box>
              )}
            </Box>
          </>
        )}
      </PanelHeader>
      <PanelContent
        disabledPadding={isMediaFullWidth && initialized && type !== 'image'}
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.min]: min,
          [classes.media]: type === 'audio' || type === 'video',
        })}
        ref={disableContextMenuRef}
      >
        {initialized ? (
          <>
            {transcript && (
              <Box>
                <Box
                  className={classes.transcript}
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: transcript }}
                />
              </Box>
            )}
            {error && (
              <Center>
                <Box textAlign="center">
                  <Box color="text.secondary">
                    {(props) => <Error fontSize="large" {...props} />}
                  </Box>
                  <Typography>
                    <Box color="text.secondary" component="span">
                      Error loading
                    </Box>
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
              </Center>
            )}
            {loading && (
              <Center>
                <CircularProgress />
              </Center>
            )}
            {!(error || loading) && url !== null && type === 'pdf' && (
              <object
                className={classes.object}
                data={url}
                height="100%"
                width="100%"
                type="application/pdf"
              />
            )}
            {!(error || loading) && url !== null && type === 'image' && (
              <>
                {(!min && max) || !!transcript ? (
                  <Image className={classes.imageFullWidth} src={url} />
                ) : (
                  <Center>
                    <Image className={classes.imageContain} src={url} />
                  </Center>
                )}
              </>
            )}
            {url !== null && (type === 'audio' || type === 'video') && (
              <Player
                className={classes.player}
                currentTime={playerSegment}
                disabled={isPlayerDisabled}
                onPlay={() => {
                  if (typeof onPlayerPlay) onPlayerPlay();
                }}
                onPlaying={() => {
                  if (typeof onPlayerPlaying === 'function')
                    onPlayerPlaying(playerRef?.current?.currentTime());
                }}
                onPause={() => {
                  if (typeof onPlayerStop === 'function')
                    onPlayerStop(playerRef?.current?.currentTime());
                }}
                onRateChange={() => {
                  if (typeof onPlayerRateChange === 'function')
                    onPlayerRateChange({
                      speed: playerRef?.current?.playbackRate(),
                      segment: playerRef?.current?.currentTime(),
                    });
                }}
                onSeeking={() => {
                  if (typeof onPlayerSeekChange === 'function')
                    onPlayerSeekChange(playerRef?.current?.currentTime());
                }}
                onWaiting={() => {
                  if (typeof onPlayerWait === 'function')
                    onPlayerWait(playerRef?.current?.currentTime());
                }}
                preset="square"
                ref={playerRef}
                src={url}
                type={`${type}/${getFileExtension(mediaFilename)}`}
              />
            )}
          </>
        ) : (
          <Skeleton
            className={classes.skeleton}
            height="100%"
            variant="rect"
            width="100%"
          />
        )}
      </PanelContent>
    </Panel>
  );
};

CoverPanel.propTypes = propTypes;
```

Can you help identify the root cause of this issue of PDF viewer on Safari? I really need help with this. Thank you so much in advance!